# Example of marionette.js layout/region structure and rendering method

Tags: marionette

I'm trying marionette.js for my backbone application but I'm a bit baffled as to how I should organize my layouts/regions and render them.

I'm looking for an example application with nested layouts and regions so I could understand a bit better. Any advice ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out this fiddles:

http://jsfiddle.net/tegon/0g2aaLxe/1/


http://jsfiddle.net/tegon/64ovLf64/

for general backbone marionette boilerplate starting point check this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410059/suggested-bootstrap-boilerplate-sample-for-backbone-marionette-application/11598371#11598371

Comment: @saniko - your fiddle has issues (in Chrome at least), because of [this](https://plus.google.com/+MikeWest/posts/28f8HS2M7cb), so i forked it and made a [patched fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erichbschulz/bbPKH/19/)

Comment: toggling teh side bar causes the click me event to not work anymore!