# Marionette examples not working in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I want to learn `Marionette` regions and layouts with some examples in `jsfiddle`, but every example I look at seems non-functional or completely blank.

For instance I just see a completely black output for the first example in the answer from this question:
[Example of marionette.js layout/region structure and rendering method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154442/example-of-marionette-js-layout-region-structure-and-rendering-method)

In the `jsfiddle` of this [Nesting Marionette regions, layouts and views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662712/nesting-marionette-regions-layouts-and-views) answer I just see:

Navigate

Content

I've tried multiple browsers and different computers but I see the same thing. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Do you have any examples I could look at?

Comment: just some "external resources" loading issues caused by using raw.github ... just link marionette properly and everything will work. (read more https://rawgit.com/faq)

Comment: What can I do to link marionette properly? I didn't see the answer in the FAQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a CDN, like https://cdnjs.com/ to load scripts on `jsfiddle`. I've forked that two examples that you sent

http://jsfiddle.net/tegon/64ovLf64/

http://jsfiddle.net/tegon/0g2aaLxe/

I've also changed the `Backbone.Marionette.Layout` to `Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView` (new class name).

Edit: The second was using `region.close()` which is deprecated. I've changed now to use `region.empty()`

http://jsfiddle.net/tegon/0g2aaLxe/1/

Comment: The one that was black now seems to work except the Toggle Sidebar button.

I'm not sure the other one works, as it just shows:
This is nav-template
This is breadcrumbs-template
This is options-template
This is content-template

Comment: The first one is correctly, it only replaces the content with the templates. I've updated the answer with second one working now.

Comment: I just updated all links in the mentioned questions to the working fiddles provided by @tegon ... gj

Comment: Good one! Thanks @rafaelcastrocouto